# Top Links editing

Tags: magento2, theme, frontend, header, toplinks

Ok, I give up. I've created a child theme based on Luma. At the very top of the page I see these links "Compare Products 0 items  My Account Create an Account Sign In" and then a detached word "or". How do I change these links tags and get rid of the "or". There is no `local.xml` that I can find.

**V 2.0.13** Luma Parent

Answer (score 2):

The file is in the source\vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\account\link\authorization.phtml

You can save this file to your own theme to override it.

In the template file line 15:

```
<li class="authorization-link" data-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('or')); ?>">
```

Change data-label value can get rid of the 'or' that you don't like.